# How to re-write a while statement as an if statement in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, csv

I wrote a script that searches an excel document for 'X', and when it finds an 'X' it copies the first column and first row associated with the 'X' into a CSV file.

I've been told that there's a better way to do this with 'if' statements. Not quite sure how.

Here's the code:

```
 import xlrd
 import csv

 ###Grab the data from sheet 1
 def get_row_values(workSheet, row):
    to_return = []
     num_cells = myWorksheet.ncols - 1
    curr_cell = -1
    while curr_cell < num_cells:
        curr_cell += 1
        cell_value = myWorksheet.cell_value(row, curr_cell)
        to_return.append(cell_value)
     return to_return

 file_path = 'foo.xlsx'
 output = []

 #Write the data
 myWorkbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_path)
 myWorksheet = myWorkbook.sheet_by_name('foosheet')
 num_rows = myWorksheet.nrows - 1
 curr_row = 0
 column_names = get_row_values(myWorksheet, curr_row)
 #print("TOTAL ENTRIES:") 
 #print len(column_names)
 #print("-----")
 framework_name = myWorksheet.cell(0,2)
 framework_version = myWorksheet.cell(0,3)
 while curr_row < num_rows:
        curr_row += 1 
        row = myWorksheet.row(curr_row)
        this_row = get_row_values(myWorksheet, curr_row)
        x = 0
        while x <len(this_row):
            if this_row[x] == 'x':
                output.append(['', fooname, foo_version, 
 foo_names[x], foo_row[0]])
                myData = [["foo1", "foo2", 
 "foo3", "foo4", "foo5"]]

                myFile = open('./results/barTemp.csv', 'w')
                with myFile:
                        writer = csv.writer(myFile)
                        writer.writerows(myData)
                        writer.writerows(output)

            x += 1

 #print output



 myFile.close()
 myWorkbook.release_resources()
```

Comment: It seems more likely that there's been a miscommunication somewhere, and you were supposed to use `for`, not `if`. Replacing `while` with `if` almost never makes sense unless you were using `while` horribly wrong.

Comment: Does the worksheet object have a row iterator? What library are you using? What is num_rows? What is get_row_values? I'm asking because I have a feeling that at least 25% of the code you show is superfluous.

Comment: Should `this_row[0]` be `this_row[x]`?

Comment: I've gone ahead and put in the entire code. Happy for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Its not necessarily better. Still the same runtime-complexity.

The difference would be a more compact line:

For example, you can change

while x < len(this_row):

to

for x in this_row:

but I see that you use the 'x' index to find column_names[x] so another approach might be better such as

for x in range(len(this_row)):